# How to parse certain tokens out of a String?

Tags: java, string

Could someone please help me parse integer values and arithematic operators from a java string.

For ex:

```
   String rule = "itemCount < 10 and itemCount >= 20";
```

From the rule String I need to retrieve, `<, 10, >= and 20` which will then be displayed in the jsp.

Comment: What about the 'and' operator? Can these rules have  additional operators? Are there always two comparisons?

Comment: Hi Groo,  I am not interested in getting "and". I need only < , 10, >=, 20

Comment: Why and where exactly did you need such a concept to implement?

Comment: Hi Lion, I am having predefined rules defined in database. I just need to read the rule from database and need to display arithmetic operators in the dropdown box and integers in the text field in jsp. Can spring expression language help me in this regard?

Comment: Is it homework? In that case you need to add the `homework` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i =0; i < rule.length; ++i) {
    if (rule[i] == "<") {
        // Code for retrieving <
    } else if (rule[i] == ">=") 
        // Code for retrieving >=
    } else {
        tryParse(rule, i);
    }
}
```

**tryParse** is the function that will recursively try to parse integers until the biggest sequence of consecutive digits found and updates the value of **i**

Comment: You are trying to invoke `equals()` on `char`. That won't work.

Comment: I am just presenting a logic, you can adapt the methods if they don't work

Answer (score 1):

Does a regular expression help you?
Maybe something like:

```
(\w+) (<|<=|==|>|>=) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (<|<=|==|>|>=) (\w+)
```

(can be optimized for sure)

When matching this expression against your string you should get 7 groups with following contents:

1: itemCount

2: <

3: 10

4: and

5: itemCount

6: >=

7: 20

See the [Pattern Class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.

But in general I am not sure if this is what you want to do.

Maybe its better to switch to a more abstract way to define your expression instead of writing it into a string.

What about something like this:

```
Rule rule = Rule.AND(
  Rule.SMALLER(itemCount, 10),
  Rule.GREATER_OR_EQUAL(itemCount, 20)
);
boolean result = rule.getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks Micha. Could you please let me know, in which package Rule class is available?